# Output non matching part of each line of all matched lines only using grep

Tags: unix, grep, pattern-matching

For example file contains following lines

```
1hai
25hai
```

Output should be

```
1
25
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Initially I tried -o and -v but got wrong. But we can do it by using regex as stated in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep` (print only the leading number of each line):

```
grep -oG '^[0-9]*' file
```

Or `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/' file
```

Comment: -P refers to perl regular expression right?? Then how will basic regular expression looks like if we have to use -G

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question.  He was asking to print out the part of a line not matching `hai`.  He wasn't asking how to print out only numbers.